# Trouble to connect to config server:

Tags: mongodb

I am using sharding.

Sometimes I get this error in MongoDB.

```
MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: localhost:30000: Couldn't get host info for localhost in /path/to/file/ on line 340
```

On 30000 port config server is running.
Mongo version: **2.4.3**

Is there any solution of this problem?

Comment: If I remember right config servers cannot be located on "localhost", you must supply an IP, I think I remember reading that somewhere and I haven't got anything to test this with atm

Comment: it seems you are running your entire sharded cluster on your local machine.  why?  are you testing something?  What are the circumstances during which you get this error?

Comment: @Sammaye Config server was running on localhost for last 1 yr. There was no any issue with this. Suddenly this issue came and now I am facing this problem continuously.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I am not running this cluster on local machine. I am using three servers for this setup.On high load I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost and problem resolved. But I don't know why it was coming ? what is the difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: This is why I asked about local machine - you can't mix localhost and valid routable host names in your configuration.